# Couchbase client is too slow on production server

Tags: .net, performance, windows-server-2008-r2, couchbase

We recently purchased a new server for our project. After that I've noticed a performance problem with Couchbase client. Then I wrote a simple load tool to compare performance on different machines:

```
internal class Program {
    private static IMemcachedClient _client;
    private static string _key = "mykey";
    private static bool _value = false;
    private static void Main() {
        _client = new CouchbaseClient();

        _client.Store(StoreMode.Set, _key, _value);
        while (true) {
            _client.Get(_key);
        }
    }
}
```

On my development machine this tool makes 35k gets per sec to localhost memcached instance. 
But on the server it's much slower - 4k gets per sec with same settings.

It is very big difference and I don't understand the reason.

Dev machine configuration:

- Windows 7 Professional x64
- Core i7-2600 3.4GHz
- 8Gb RAM

Production server configuration:

- Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise x64
- 2x Xeon E5645 2.4GHz
- 48Gb RAM

Can you help me to understand why server is so slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a hardware issue. Six-core Xeons or motherboard. Hoster changed them both and now issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think that production server is't slow.
I suppose when you run you test with dev server you run through localhost.
Localhost is much faster then real network interface.

Comment: Can you compare windows performance counters: cpu, io write, network.
What is differ?